# What is the weight of the bulletproof cockpit doors of a Boeing 747?

Tags: aircraft-design, cockpit, boeing-747

What is the weight of the bulletproof cockpit doors of a Boeing 747 built prior to 9/11? Do the doors weigh the same for later models, like the Boeing 747-8 specifically? How many fewer passengers do they have to carry in light of the added weight?

Comment: Downvoters, please remember to include an explanation. The OP can't make the question better if they don't know what's wrong

Comment: Why did this receive 5 downvotes? It's a perfectly valid, on-topic question.

Comment: @DeltaLima People seem to be downvoting the user and not the questions. After the [meta post](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3481/1696), people seem to be following the rule of "if you can't say anything nice, don't say anything at all."

Comment: @foot, thank you for your response. If you are right that the user is downvoted instead of the question, I wonder on what basis that is done. In my opinion, voting should be based on the content of the post. I understand that voting is sometimes biased based on historic behaviour of a user, because post are judged in that historic context. The bottom line is that this is a perfectly valid, clearly phrased, aviation related question. Down voting such a question doesn't help this site, nor the person who asked the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [federalregister.gov](https://www.federalregister.gov/d/05-8259/p-138):

> The FAA also assumed that the average safety door system adds 100 pounds to a large airplane. This additional weight would have minimal impacts on weight and distance limitations.

For a large airplane, like say the 747, it seems the weight addition is around 100 lb (including the other safety features such as the surveillance). As for the exact weight before/after, this information is not readily available as the doors are not sold to the public. But feel free to get in touch with Boeing if it's for research/educational purposes and such.

If the information provided by the seller on this [eBay item](https://www.ebay.com/itm/747-400-Flight-Deck-Cockpit-door-As-removed-P-N-232U2110-400G-/261758098555) is correct, then the weight of a 747-400 door is 59 lb. And [also from eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Boeing-737-Anti-Bullet-Proof-Ballistic-Door-Cockpit-Door/192316942880), is a bullet proof 737 door shown below.

[image]

Comment: According to Wikipedia, a 747-8 has a MTOW of 987,000lb, so the door would be about 0.01% of that. I'd be surprised if that small difference had any impact on the number of passengers carried, considering that larger variations must already happen routinely because of luggage and freight.

Comment: @Pondlife - it does have an impact on the loooooong run, like switching from paper charts and manuals to an iPad.

Comment: Definitely, my point was just that I don't think anyone is ripping passenger seats out of 747s because of the added weight of cockpit door reinforcements